# Tortoise SVN log "URL .. doesn't exist"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using Windows 7 Professional and Tortoise SVN 1.9.4.

So I right click on a directory under SVN control and choose `Show SVN Log`. Multiple revisions are shown. I select multiple contiguous revisions, none of these rename or move any file or directory. The third area of the log window shows me the files affected by the selected range. I double-click on a file to view the differences. Instead of seeing differences I instead see a popup error:

"Subversion reported an error. URL ...://svnrepository.MYDOMAIN.com/svn/X/Y/trunk/somefile.txt doesn't exist"

What can cause this?

Comment: Did you update the working copy before running 'Show log'?

Comment: I did yes. I have this issue often.

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case, it means the file I want to open doesn't exist in one of the revisions I've selected so the diff crashes. Looking for a work around too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very old question, but in case anyone else lands here (like I did today), I think I know what's going on. The problem is, if you select multiple revisions, the "Action" modifier won't be displayed in the bottom pane. If you were to instead select one revision at a time, you are likely to discover that the problematic file ("somefile.txt", in OP's example) will be listed as "Added" or "Moved". (Again, that information is hidden when you select all the revisions at once.) As mentioned in the comments, this causes SVN to choke when you attempt to open that file in a differencing tool.

Unfortunately, the only workaround at this point appears to be grouping only those revisions which appear *after* the new file was added, and diff those.