# TortoiseSVN "URL...doesn't exist" message truncated

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Similar to [the question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882013/tortoise-svn-log-url-doesnt-exist), when I select multiple revisions in a Show-Log dialog and try to diff them all, I often get one or more error messages that the file (or URL) doesn't exist. The PROBLEM is that the error dialog *truncates the file name*, so I have no idea which files got skipped. (See screenshot.) Is there any other way to access the full information in these error messages?

I tried using DebugView, [as described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614894/how-to-debug-something-in-tortoisesvn) here, but these error messages were not displayed there.

[image]

Comment: If the dialogue is not resizeable, you can probably click on the URL until it's fully selected and copy it elsewhere (or maybe even Ctrl+C and get the complete dialogue).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, unfortunately the dialog is not resizable and the URL is not selectable. Nothing about the dialog is interactive in any way (except the Close button).